# Congrats to 2018 Batch of MVPs!

Tags: discussion, mvp

Salesforce StackExchange continues it's legacy of producing MVPs for another year. Many congratulations to Santanu Boral for being inducted as a Salesforce MVP and to those who got renewed for another year!

https://success.salesforce.com/mvp - Note that this link contains the full list of MVPs (old and new)

The official blog announcement is here - https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2018/03/2018-salesforce-mvps.html

Stealing this from an earlier year's post as it is most appropriate - SF.SE wouldn't be the same without the extensive knowledge, expertise and experience all of the new, present and past MVPs share with us.

Keep the SF.SE flag flying high!

Comment: Very proud to have Santanu join our ranks!

Comment: Congrats @SantanuBoral !

Comment: congrats @SantanuBoral, well deserved!

Comment: Congrats @santanuBoral - good to see all your hard work pay off

Comment: Congrats @Menzman/@ChristianMenzinger - great work!

Answer (score 27):

Thank you so much everyone who has helped me during this journey. I do not want a take any specific names as I could miss someone I know. Contributing at SFSE actually helped me a lot to keep myself as a developer at my heart. Though I didn't get a chance to write code on daily basis but this awesome community has cherished me to do that.

We know that SFSE will produce many MVPs in new future as always.

I truly believe at **Learn with helping others**.

Thank you all.

Comment: Congrats, Santanu.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations !!!!

Comment: Congrats, Santanu.

Comment: Congratulations Santanu :) well Deserved!!!

Comment: Many Congratulations Santanu!!

Comment: Heartiest congratulations!

Comment: Congrats Santanu, you are truly an inspiration.

Comment: you rock Santanu!

Comment: Congrats!! Welcome to the MVP clan ;)

Comment: Hearty congrats Santanu!

Comment: Congrats and welcome!

Comment: Congrats Santanu. Saw you were in the list and it's well deserved!